# Yii2 an internal server error occured while deploying the project on production server

Tags: php, yii, yii2

The project is running fine on the local system but when i deploying the project on the production server then i got the error which is coming from this path 
vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php

```
 if (YII_DEBUG) {
                if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
                    echo $msg . "\n";
                } else {
                    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($msg, ENT_QUOTES, Yii::$app->charset) . '</pre>';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'An internal server error occurred.';
            }
```

When i hit the url then screen show blank with above error "An internal server error occurred." and the error coming from above code.

Here is my index.php

```
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
//defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
//defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Comment: Have you check yii2 requirements in production server?

Comment: I don't know about that please tell me how can i check that

Comment: Yii2 will provice requirements.php file, which is available in basic or advanced app. run this file in your browers through production server url.

Comment: requirements.php is available is inside the vendor/yiisoft/yii2/requirements/requirements.php

Comment: how can i run this http://example.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/requirements/requirements.php like this?

Comment: No you can't access this file directly. copy this requirements.php to web and run like example.com/requiremnts.php

Comment: okay got it will do that

Comment: Are you using yii2 basic or advanced app?

Comment: i don't know because i am not a developer right now i just copy the basic app requirement file for yii2

Comment: You can always check the last error of the application in the app log <APP_DIRECTORY>/runtime/logs/app.log

Comment: @IrfanAli: its working now its need php-mbstring extenison